# Calling method in parent UIViewController, after adding by addSubview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, parent, addsubview

I have a UIViewController that is creating another view controller, and adding its view as a subview:

In the parent UIViewController:

```
SlateMoreView* subView = [[SlateMoreView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SlateMoreView" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:subView.view];
```

I then need to call a method from the subview, in the parent view.

I have seen how to do this when I am adding the sub UIViewController using [self.navigationController pushViewController: subView animated: YES], because I can find the parent using this kind of code:

In the sub view UIViewController:

```
NSArray* viewControllerArray = [self.navigationController viewControllers]
int parentViewControllerIndex = [viewControllerArray count] - 2;
SlateView* slateView = [viewControllerArray objectAtIndex:parentViewControllerIndex];
```

...and then I can send messages to it. But since I added the sub view manually by using addSubView, I can't do this.

Can anyone think of how I can talk to my parent UIViewController?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`UIView`s have a `superview` property which seems to be what you are looking for.

In addition you probably don't want to nest `UIViewController`'s view like that unless you are very deliberately building a custom contain view controller. See http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/

Comment: Read that article. Very informative, thank you. The reason I chose to do it this way is because its a smaller view that moves in over the parent view. Should I be looking into the modal view controller stuff do you think?

Comment: Presenting a view controller as a modal won't give you control of it's position or allow you to change its expected size.
I think what you probably want to do it either:
1. Just construct a view without a dedicated controller, add it as a subview, and manage it as necessary using your existing controller.
or
2. Create a view with some custom controller responsible for managing it's behavior. Have that controller extend NSObject rather than UIViewController so that you don't have the incorrect assumption that it can behave like a UIViewController normally does.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider if your problem can be solved by using NSNotifications. You could post a notification from your subview when an event happens that interested listeners (your superview) need to know about . When the superview receives the notification, it can run whatever code you wish. All the while the subview never needs to know about the superview.

This is one way to make your classes less dependant on each other.

You could also use delegation as another option.

Answer (score 0):

When you add your view as a subview to a view hierarchy, you put it in the responder chain. You can go up the responder chain to reach the view controller as a `UIView` controlled by a `UIViewController` has the `UIViewController` as its `nextResponder`.

```
id object = theSubview;
do {
    object = [object nextResponder];
} while ( ![object isMemberOfClass:[YourViewController class]] );

// object has the view controller you need.
```